# How to map JSON String to model class using Object Mapper in swift

Tags: json, swift, model, objectmapper

My model class is like:

```
class CalendarTaskModel: Mappable {

     var kpiColor: String?
     var kpi: String?
     var date: String?

     required init?(map: Map) {
        //Code here
     }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
         kpiColor <- map["kpiColor"]
         kpi <- map["kpi"]
         date <- map["date"]
     }
 }
```

I have an object mapped with a model class.

```
var taskDetails: [CalendarTaskModel]?
```

As my object is of array type so I Want to map JSON string to object using ObjectMapper like the code below.

```
code 1: taskDetails = Mapper<[CalendarTaskModel]>().map(JSONString: jsonStr)
//
code 2: taskDetails = Mapper<CalendarTaskModel>().map(JSONString: jsonStr)
```

but I am getting errors [image] && [image] Please suggest how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your calendar task compliant with the mappable type?

Comment: Yes, it's mappable.

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: I am using ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! You should use the `mapArray` method instead:

```
let jsonStr = ...
var taskDetails: [CalendarTaskModel]?
taskDetails = Mapper<CalendarTaskModel>().mapArray(JSONfile: jsonStr)
```

This is because the `map` method does not return an array.

As for the code 1 that you provided, the `[CalendarTaskModel]` type (equivalent to `Array<CalendarTaskModel>` is *not* compliant with that mappable protocol. I suspect it is possible to make it compliant, for instance with more complex logic, but the library encourages you to use the method I suggested. Best of luck!

Comment: Alex, I tried with mapArray but it didn't work. I am getting nil in taskDetails.

Comment: Shiv, can you show me an example JSON string that you are working with?

Comment: Here is an example of json *{ "kpiMeasureBy": "", "calculatedBy": "", "enumKpiMeasureBy": "", "calendar": [ { "date": "02\/08\/2018", "kpi": "-", "taskList": [ { "totalClaimWithCurrency": "MYR0.00", "enumUserType": "SALESPERSON", "taskImageList": [ ], "followUpNotes": "", "requestList": [ ], "totalSubTask": 0, "subTaskList": [ ], "userPhone": "0123456789", "remark": "", "cancelReason": "cancel", "claimList": [ ], "subTask": "" } ], "kpiColor": "GREY" } ] }*

Comment: This does not look like a CalendarTaskModel to me. There are other parameters surrounding it, e.g. `"kpiMeasureBy" = ...`

Comment: Here is an example a correct JSON for a single task:

`{"kpi": "hello", "date": "today", "kpiColor": "blue"}`

Comment: An array of them would look like this:

```[{"kpi": "hello", "date": "today", "kpiColor": "blue"},
{"kpi": "hello", "date": "today", "kpiColor": "blue"}, ...]```

Comment: Alex Sorry I just removed some keys from original Json.

Comment: For your use case: read the "Easy Mapping of Nested JSON" section at this page: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#easy-mapping-of-nested-objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177536/discussion-between-shiv-jaiswal-and-alexandre-cassagne).